# glUniformMatrix4fv causing GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c++, opengl

When I call glUniformMatrix4fv or glUniform4fv in the below code it raises GL_INVALID_OPERATION every time, I have tried changing how I pass it the matrix data, the count I pass id, I've checked the model ids and shader program but can't figure out why it does it.

Here is the shader:

## version 330

```
uniform vec4 projection; /* view port / perspective */
uniform vec4 model; /* object */
uniform vec4 view; /*camera */
in vec3 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

GLuint getShader(const char* shaderName, GLenum shaderType) {
    /* Read file */
    std::ifstream shaderFile;
    shaderFile.open(shaderName, std::ios_base::in);

    if(!shaderFile) {
        std::cout <<  shaderName << " not found" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::string line;
    std::string shaderData;
    while(std::getline(shaderFile, line)) {
        shaderData += line + "\n";
    }

    shaderFile.close();

    /* Create shader */
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);

    if(shader == 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create shader for " << shaderName << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    const char *shaderStr = shaderData.c_str();

    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shaderStr, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    /* Check compile status */
    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if(status != GL_TRUE) {
        GLint logLength;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);

        GLchar* infoLog = new GLchar[logLength + 1];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, logLength, nullptr, infoLog);

        std::cout << shaderName << " failed to compile: " << infoLog << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    return shader;
}

int end(const char* message) {
    glfwTerminate();

    if(message != nullptr) {
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    /* Initial checks */
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return end("Failed to startup GLFW");
    }

    /* Create the window */
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "3D world prototyping", nullptr, nullptr);

    if (!window) {
        return end("Failed to create window.");
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); //make the window active

    /* Startup GLEW */
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        return end("Failed to startup GLEW");
    }

    /* Start OpenGL constants */
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500);

    /* Support for multiple shaders without the need to switch attributes */
    GLuint vertexArray;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);

    /* Create buffers */
    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);

    /* Shape vectors */
    GLfloat verticies[] = { //X, Y, Z
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,

            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,

            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,

            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,

            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,

            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,

            -1.0f, -1.0f, -0.5f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -0.5f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -0.5f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -0.5f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -0.5f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -0.5f
    };
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticies), verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    /* Load in the shaders */
    GLuint fragmentShader = getShader("fragmentShader.glsl", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLuint vertexShader = getShader("vertexShader.glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    if (fragmentShader == 0 || vertexShader == 0) {
        return end("Failed to load shaders");
    }

    /* Setup the shaders */
    /* Create the shader program and use it */
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    if (shaderProgram == 0) {
        return end("Failed to create shader program");
    }

    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor"); //tell opengl about the out color variable
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if(glIsProgram(shaderProgram) != GL_TRUE) {
        return end("Failed to create shader program");
    }

    /* Positioning */
    //FOV, Screen ratio, display range short, display range long
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(4.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f), // Camera
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), // Where the camera looks up
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)  // Pitch of the head
    );
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    /* Rendering and logic */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        /* Shutdown logic */
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)) {
            break;
        }

        /* Clear */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);

        /* Logic */
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        GLint projectionId = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");
        GLint viewId = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
        GLint modelId = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");

GLenum error = glGetError();
        if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "Uniform error " << error << ": " << glewGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
            return end("");
        }
        else if(projectionId == -1) {
            return end("Projection ID failed to load");
        }
        else if(viewId == -1) {
            return end("View ID failed to load");
        }
        else if(modelId == -1) {
            return end("Model ID failed to load");
        }

        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewId, 3, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

        error = glGetError();
        if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "View uniform matrix error " << error << ": " << glewGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        }

        glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionId, 3, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

        error = glGetError();
        if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "Projection matrix error " << error << ": " << glewGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        }

        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelId, 3, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

        error = glGetError();
        if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "Model uniform matrix error " << error << ": " << glewGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        }

        /* Tell opengl about all the attributes */
        GLint positionAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");

        if(positionAttribute == -1) {
            std::cout << "Error: position attribute failed to load" << std::endl;
            end("");
        }
        error = glGetError();
        if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "Position attribute error " << error << ": " << glewGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        }

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);

        error = glGetError();
        if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "Vertex enable error " << error << ": " << glewGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        }

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

        error = glGetError();
        if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "Buffer bind error " << error << ": " << glewGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        }

        glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); //because not just XYZ need to tell opengl the size of the stride

        error = glGetError();
        if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "Vertex attrib pointer error " << error << ": " << glewGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        }

        /* Draw */
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

        error = glGetError();
        if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "gl draw arrays " << error << ": " << glewGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        }

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);

        error = glGetError();
        if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "gl disable attrib error " << error << ": " << glewGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        }

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

        error = glGetError();
        if(error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "Error " << error << ": " << glewGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);
    return end(nullptr);
}
```

Comment: When your shader doesn't use some uniform, it may get optimized out and removed completely from shader code. In that case glGetUniformLocation will return -1. Check if viewId has any meaningful value. That's the step you forgot.

Comment: Just added that now (And updated post code), none of the else if fired, they all have actual values

Comment: This won't help you fix your problem, but you should only be querying those uniform locations after you link your program, rather than once per-application main loop. They won't change locations unless you re-link the program, and it's much easier to validate them once at load time than every iteration of your loop.

Comment: With that said, can you show the body of the shader in question? I get the impression that `projectionId` is not declared as `mat4 [3]`, and that would make that particular API call invalid.

Comment: Okay I'll move them there, I did have them there originally but when I browsed for example code people were putting them in their loop, I assumed they got reset by useProgram or something. EDIT: Sure I'll add it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the particular uniforms in question, you are using the wrong API call to set them.

Those are vectors, rather than matrices. You would use `glUniform4fv (...)` rather than `glUniformMatrix4fv (...)`. The latter function assumes that you are setting 1 or more 4x4 matrix uniforms (your passed parameters are telling it that `projection` is supposed to be an array of 3 `mat4`s).

---

I believe the appropriate function calls would look like this in your situation:

```
glUniform4fv (modelId, 1, glm::value_ptr(model)); // Fill 1 4D vector, not an array of vectors
```

Comment: That makes sense, I just saw the glm mat4 as a 4D matrix when I guess it is a  4D vector instead. Thanks for your help, I'm no longer getting any errors but my cube still isn't drawing, any chance you could follow up with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540117/opengl-cube-not-being-rendered

Comment: @user1763295: Sorry, I sort of answered your question and then had to run yesterday. I think your problem is that those variables declared `vec4` should actually be `mat4`. My answer works when they're declared `vec4`, but that's probably not the original intention.

Answer (score 2):

Setting uniforms will result in the `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error when the setter function you are calling does not match the data type of the uniform you are trying to set.

Since you declared your uniforms as *vectors*:

```
uniform vec4 projection; /* view port / perspective */
uniform vec4 model; /* object */
uniform vec4 view; /*camera */
```

you can't use the *matrix* setters. You should change your uniformst to `mat4` to make your code work.

As a small side note: it will *not* generate an error if you try to set a uniform with location -1 (meaning the uniform is not present or has been optimized out). This is explicitely allowed, possibly to allow for generic frameworks where a shader might just use a sub-set of the uniforms.